# Is $\mathbb{R}^*\oplus \mathbb{R}^* \simeq \mathbb{C}^*$?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

My question is whether $\mathbb{R}^*\oplus \mathbb{R}^* \simeq \mathbb{C}^*$. I think this isn't true because $(0,1)^2 = (0,1)$, but $i^2 = -1$. I can't quite figure out how to make this rigorous though.

I do know that $\mathbb{R}\oplus \mathbb{R} \simeq \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Well, $(0,1)$ is not in $\mathbb R^{*}\oplus\mathbb R^{*}$, so it is not clear that you mean by that.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Yes, you are right.

Comment: There is a subtlety here.  Do you want to know if there is *any* group isomorphism at all between $\mathbb R^*\oplus\mathbb R^*$ and $\mathbb C^*$, or only if a specific ring isomorphism $\mathbb R\oplus\mathbb R\to \mathbb C$ can ever define such a group isomorphism?  In the latter case, note that we're dealing with fields, and the only non-invertible element in a field is the zero element.  Is your proposed set of units precisely the non-zero elements, or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on to something, but you don't know in advance whether or not your potential isomorphism will send $(0,1)$ to $i$.  Edit: And as pointed out by Thomas Andrews, $(0,1)$ is not an element of $\mathbb{R}^* \oplus \mathbb{R}^*$.

How many elements in $\mathbb{R}^* \oplus \mathbb{R}^*$ have their square equal to $-1 = (-1,-1)$?  How many elements in $\mathbb{C}^*$ have their square equal to $-1$?

You could also ask how many elements have their square equal to $1$.

Comment: Ah. so no element have their square equal to $(-1,-1)$. And two elements have square equal to $-1$ in $\mathbb{C}^*$.

Comment: You can similarly and more easily just ask how many element have square $1$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Both have two elements whose square is $1$. $(-1,-1)$ and $(1,1)$ and $1$ and $-1$?

Comment: No, @JohnDoe. There are more in $\mathbb R^*\oplus\mathbb R^*$.